# logging soap requests in flex 3

Tags: soap, flexbuilder

I'm trying to consume a SOAP webservice from an Adobe Flex 3 application, but the server tell me "Invalid SOAP Envelope. SOAP Body does not contain a message nor a fault". I already wrote other test clients (with both Delphi and C#) and I'm sure it's all ok on the server side, so I need to examine the SOAP envelope Flex is sending out to the server. How to do that? I think it should be some event to listen (in the BaseSys class?) to get the envelope before it will be sent.

Comment: Are you using RemObjects for the webservice? I'm seeing the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your replies but the problem was the status code 500 ([flex can handle code 200 only](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14803))

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run a proxy. Paros is an easy one, written in Java, and therefore multi-platform by nature : http://www.parosproxy.org/index.shtml

Also, if you do not use it already, you should install firebug : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1843

The network monitoring tab should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. If you are using Flex Builder you can try to generate a client for your web service using the **Import Web Service** feature from the **Data** menu and ether use it directly or just investigate the generated code for clues.
2. Check out the documentation for web services from Flex SDK as it may be a problem with the supported SOAP versions. Check to see that both Flex SDK and your server are using compatible versions.